# Set cookie (with JS) for whole domain not specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, session-cookies

I have a simple little script which I am using to set a cookie:

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

The problem I have this cookie is only set on one page, not across the whole domain.

How can I adjust this function so that the cookie remains across the whole domain?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can specifiy domain `;domain=.example.com` as well as path `;path=/` ("/" set cookie in whole domain)

```
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires +";path=/";
```